# Angle between vector and its image under rotation

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

I am given $\theta_0 \in [0,2\pi]$ fixed and $$ T(\hat{v})=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
cos(\theta_0) & -sin(\theta_0) \\
sin(\theta_0) & cos(\theta_0) \\
 \end{array} \right) $$

I want to prove that the angle between $\hat{v}$ and $T(\hat{v})$ is exactly $\theta_0$

I uses the definition of the dot product $\hat{v}\cdot T(\hat{v})= \|\hat{v}\|\|T(\hat{v})\|cos(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $\hat{v}$ and $T(\hat{v})$.

I'm got to $cos(\theta)=cos(\theta_0)$ but Idon't know how to conclude that $\theta=\theta_0$.

Thanks.

Comment: $cos(\theta)=cos(\theta_0)$ then $\theta = \theta_0$ or $\theta = - \theta_0.$  The difference between those is a clockwise or a counterclockwise rotation..  $\theta = \theta_0 + 2n\pi$ is a possibility, but why can  we waive that one away?

Comment: because $\theta_0 \in [0,2\pi]$?

Answer (score 1):

If $\cos \theta = \cos \theta_0$ with both of them in $[0, 2 \pi]$ then I assume you know that either $\theta = \theta_0$ or $\theta_0 = 2 \pi - \theta$.  But of course saying that the angle between two lines is $2 \pi - \theta$ is the same as saying that the angle between them is $\theta$; it just depends on whether you're measuring the long way or the short way around.

Comment: So you are saying that I can only conclude that $\theta=\theta_0+2k\pi$ but geometrically it's the same so I can just "rule them out"?

Comment: Not quite.  There's also the possibility that $\theta = - \theta_0 + 2 \pi$.  (You can actually rule out this possibility by doing further work, but it's not needed here.)